# Where did the phrase "гладить против шерсти" come from?

Tags: лексикон, этимология, выражения

I figured out through its usage and some Google-Fu, that *гладить против шерсти* means rubbing the wrong way, but can someone explain to me why "touch/press against the wool"? Where did this phrase come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They also say: "Не гладь кошку против шерсти".
Cats don't like it when you rub them in the direction opposite to the one the fur grows.